# Searchkick::ImportError — index_not_found_exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have an API method for reindexing which is being called once every day. Sometimes reindexing through Searchkick exception `index_not_found_exception` and reindex process stops in the middle.

Log from a couple of different days.

> A Searchkick::ImportError occurred in lodgings#reindex:

```
{
  "type"=>"index_not_found_exception",
  "reason"=>"no such index",
  "index_uuid"=>"_na_",
  "index"=>"lodgings_production_20190626001429368"
} on item with id '206'
```

> Same error with different item id

```
{
  "type"=>"index_not_found_exception",
  "reason"=>"no such index",
  "index_uuid"=>"_na_",
  "index"=>"lodgings_production_20190615004229543"
} on item with id '1233'
```

***elasticsearch: 6.0.3, 
searchkick: 3.1.0***

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Have some assumptions but not exactly

Comment: I am in this situation too. Any progress so far?

Comment: clear index `YourModel.search_index.delete` and reindex again `YourModel.reindex`